# Firebase making sure async functions are completed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How to make sure my `.remove` calls are completed? Am I right with code below? Recently I've got a case when this function wasn't completed at all. So could you explain async calls. Thanks.

```
exports.UserDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
    var uid = event.data.uid;
    admin.database().ref("notes/" + uid).remove();
    admin.database().ref("users/" + uid).remove();
    admin.database().ref("providers/" + uid).remove();
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You must return a promise from your function that's resolved when all the asynchronous work is complete.  Understanding how asynchronous programming works is [critical for using Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Each one of those calls to [remove()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#remove) returns a promise, so you need to collect them all into an array and pass them to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get another promise that's resolved after all the work is complete.

```
exports.UserDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
    const uid = event.data.uid;
    const p1 = admin.database().ref("notes/" + uid).remove();
    const p2 = admin.database().ref("users/" + uid).remove();
    const p3 = admin.database().ref("providers/" + uid).remove();
    return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);
});
```

Comment: Is it ok to call with empty array `return Promise.all([]);`?

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko The documentation for Promise.all() that I linked to addresses your question: Return value - An already resolved Promise if the iterable passed is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you should return `Promise` when you work with `async` tasks in firebase-function

checkout [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

```
var uid = event.data.uid;

return admin.database().ref("notes/" + uid).remove()
.then(() => admin.database().ref("users/" + uid).remove())
.then(() => admin.database().ref("providers/" + uid).remove())
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is also good but top answer is more elegant